# How to define rating sheet model for an interview?

Tags: django, django-models

[image]

Pardon the bad drawing.

## Notations:

- I - Interview
- R1,R2,R3,R4 - Rounds
- RT - Rating Sheet
- A0, A1, A2, A4 - Aspect(Text Fields) under Rating sheet.

Models:

```
class Interview(models.Model):
    date = ............

class Round(models.Model):
    interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview)

class RatingSheet(models.Model):
    name = ............

class Aspects(models.Model):
    sheet= models.ForeignKey(RatingSheet)
```

I need a rating sheet to be filled for each interview. That sheet will hold ratings (1-10) for each aspect for each Round.

**What have I tried:**

I have thought of creating a form dynamically for an Interview with N rounds and accept ratings as drop down . 
And I collect all via request.POST. And create a dictionary like:

```
rating_interview_1 = {'interview_pk':
         {
                     'Round1': {'ASP1': 5, 'ASP2':10},
                     'Round2': {'ASP1': 5, 'ASP2':10},
                     'Round3': {'ASP1': 5, 'ASP2':9},
            }
                      }
```

And then save it to database somehow. I think this can be difficult to edit or maintain. Can I get some suggestions on the correct way to design this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. Took 2 weeks of thinking. This is too complex to answer.
But one thing I learned is...there is always a way to organise you models to store data . Other wise retrieval of the same will be a real pain in the future.

**Solution:**

*We need more models .*

```
class InterviewRatingSheet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='MySheet')
    interview = models.ForeignKey(Interview, null=True)
    round_name = models.OneToOneField(Round, null=True)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class RatingAspect(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, default='', blank=True)
    interview_rating_sheet = models.ForeignKey(InterviewRatingSheet)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

So for a "**Round**", there will be only one "**InterviewRatingSheet**" and each sheet will have "**RatingAspect**"s same as "**Aspects**".

You can see the whole code in this link:
https://github.com/arindam31/django-interview-manager